# How to find vertex in python (turtle graphics)?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I am producing fractal trees using turtle module in python. To calculate fractal dimension of the trees, I need to know y-coordinate of apex of the tree. I used pyautogui.position() to find the tree's height manually by pointing mouse at the top of the tree. It takes a long time, therefore here comes my question:

Is there build-in function to find maximum height of the drawing in turtle? If no, is there some other way to find it? I have attached example of the produced pictures below. Thank you in advance.

[Example of generated fractal tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Xy6y.png)

[image]

Comment: Can you share the code?

Comment: Nice! Fractal trees. I'd love to see the code not only to help, but to read like @JonathanDrukker

Answer (score 0):

Set a variable to keep track of the maximum Y position, update it during your drawing functions, then zero it out once those functions complete a fractal.

```
#! /usr/bin/python3

from turtle import Turtle, Screen
turtle, screen  = Turtle(), Screen()

##~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

screen.setup( width = 600, height = 600 )
screen.title('Maximum Recursion')
turtle.speed( 0 )

maxY = 0  ##  empty forward-declaration

def recursive_draw( step, length ):
    global maxY

    turtle.forward( length )
    turtle.right( 7 )

    if turtle.ycor() > maxY:  maxY = turtle.ycor()  ##  update when needed

    if step > 0:  recursive_draw( step -1, length *0.8 )

for i in range( 50, 130 ):
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.setheading( i )
    turtle.setpos( 0, -300 )
    turtle.pendown()
    recursive_draw( 20, i )

turtle.hideturtle()
print( maxY )

screen.exitonclick()

##  eof  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```